# Printing the value stored in structure into a Qt table?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a structure or a linked list like this:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int k;
    char *mesage;
    struct Node *next;
} node;
```

I want to input the value of `k`, print it and after that a window screen will be open displaying all input values in the form of a table which will be created by the Qt library.

Comment: You should look into QTableWidget (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtablewidget.html)

Comment: thanks but it helps to create table.i want to link the data stored in structure with the values to be inputted in the table @piwi

Comment: If it's a table and not a tree, then you may be better off calling your class/struct something like `Row`. To me at least, Node implies a hierarchical structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reimplement [QAbstractTableModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstracttablemodel.html) then use a [QTableWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html) to access it.

Edit: I just noticed your model looks tree based rather than table based so you should really use [QAbstractItemModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QAbstractItemModel.html) with [QTreeView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html). If your data is genuinely a tree then this isn't too painful as you can use the default implementations of most methods. It becomes annoying when you're trying to make non-tree data look like a tree. Best to read through [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) of model/view programming in Qt before starting.

The best code examples are the ones which come with Qt Creator (for example, [this one](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/itemviews-simpletreemodel.html)).

Comment: Can you please help me with a code on this including a basic structure that i defined above and then creating a table with QT
@Styne666

Comment: No its not a tree type thing.
in actual i will take a data from a network type something.the data will have two to three fields like ID(as i mentioned as k in structure),message and maybe one more field.then what i want is to display those values in a table format using QT.So by this i thought to create a structure that will first save the value taken from networks into it and then will transfer those into table values.These data that i will be getting from network can be 500-600 or more and less in number and thus similarly the size of table will be increased automatically.
@Styne666

Comment: can you please write a complete code for this including structure,QT table part written above by you,a main function also through which i will input the k and message value by cin.the headers of the table can be ID and MESSAGE
@Styne666

Answer (score 0):

```
Node node;

node.k = 5;

QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(this);

QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem();
item->setData(node.k, Qt::DisplayRole);

model->appendRow(item);

QTableView* table = new QTableView(this);
table->setModel(model);
```

Comment: If you implement it this way, then I don't think changing the data via the view updates `node.k`.

Comment: To do that you can add a hidden column with a pointer to each node, connect to the `itemChanged(QStandardItem * item)` signal and then update the node you need.

Comment: No its not a tree type thing. in actual i will take a data from a network type something.the data will have two to three fields like ID(as i mentioned as k in structure),message and maybe one more field.then what i want is to display those values in a table format using QT.So by this i thought to create a structure that will first save the value taken from networks into it and then will transfer those into table values.These data that i will be getting from network can be 500-600 or more and less in number and thus similarly the size of table will be increased automatically. @hank

Comment: Using `model->appendRow(QStandardItem*)` will let you "automatically" increase the size of your table. If you need to add several items to one row you can use `model->appendRow(QList<QStandardItem*>)`.

Comment: can you please write a complete code for this including structure,QT table part written above by you,a main function also through which i will input the k and message value by cin.the headers of the table can be ID and MESSAGE
@hank

Comment: I won't write "a complete code" for you. And I think nobody here will. The answer to the question "how to write some data to a table" has already been given.

Comment: but how to set headers to the table give path to data like k has to go in first column and message to the second. 
@hank